# nativescript: modal property is undefined

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm create datepicker modal select library on nativescript.

```
var pagesModule = require("ui/page");
var datePickerModule = require("ui/date-picker");
var moment = require('momentjs');
var frame = require('ui/frame');

module.exports.init = function(tarih, callBack) {
   var dt = new datePickerModule.DatePicker();
   var page = new pagesModule.Page();
   page.content = dt;
   page.height = 250;
   var parent = frame.topmost().currentPage;
   parent.modal.showModal(page, '', function() {
      callBack();
   });
};
```

I'm calling this library on main js file;

```
var dm = require('../../../lib/dateModal');
exports.tarihCagir = function(nesne) {
    dm.init('', function() {
        console.log('kapatıldı');
    });
};
```

I'm getting this error; 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined.

This problem may be not complicated but i'm newbie for nativescript.

Comment: I'm solved problem. Changed parent.modal.showModal code to parent.showModal.

Comment: You should post an answer to your question. =)

Comment: Thanks. add a answer.

Comment: You can also mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm solved problem. Changed parent.modal.showModal code to parent.showModal.

Comment: Did this work for you on `Android`? After calling `showModal`, is `parent.modal === undefined`? I have it working on `iOS` but on `Android` modal is always `undefined`;